# MongoDB design for multiple auth user accounts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a backend with nodeJS, Express and MongoDB / mongoose...

My users can signUp/Login with Google or email and password. But now my question is what's the best option of building a model for that.

My first option is this:

```
{
    firstname: myname,
    lastname: mylastname',
    email: 'email@example.com',
    accounts: [
         { provider: google,
           idGoogle: myid, 
         },
         { provider: simple,
           email: my@email.com,
           password: myp4ssw0rd
         }
      ]
}
```

or:

```
    {
        firstname: myname,
        lastname: mylastname',
        email: 'email@example.com',
        accounts: [
             { id: q1w2e3,provider:google},
             { id: r4t5y5, provider:simple},
          ]
    }
```

and a reference to another collection

```
    {
        _id:q1w2e3,
        provider:google
        idGoogle:wqwqe24},
    {
        id: r4t5y5, 
        provider:simple,
        email:my@email.com
        password: myp4ssw0rd
    }
```

My main goal is optimal performance with many users

Comment: Many users is not a problem, many auth accounts per user (1000s) could be a problem.

Comment: Your queries against this collection are important to answer you question.  What are the shapes of the queries you use for this data?

Comment: @barrypicker each user only can have 2 accounts. And I use this 

"  await User.findOne().and([{"accounts.email": req.body.email},{"accounts.provider":req.body.provider }])  "

Comment: You could use a third option too - `{ firstname: 'myname', lastname: 'mylastname', email: 'email@example.com', account: { provider: 'google', idGoogle: 'myid', } },
{ firstname: 'myname', lastname: 'mylastname', email: 'email@example.com', account: { provider: 'simple', email: 'my@email.com', password: 'myp4ssw0rd' } }`

Comment: @barrypicker Mmhh I chose the last two options because is like having a profile and then the users can access their profile* with any of their registered accounts

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a separate collection and lookup. MongoDB will manage the embedded document without much overhead. And if it starts degrading, just add an index.

The simplicity of queries with the embedded document outweighs any overhead.